# Error with plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin: configuration scaffolding: null Message

Tags: grails

I keep getting the following error:

> Error 2015-10-30 11:34:01,762 [Thread-9] ERROR
>   plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Error configuration scaffolding: null
>   Message: null    Line | Method ->> 619 | run in java.lang.Thread - - -
>
> ---
>
> Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   racetrackapp.RaceController.propertyMissing() is applicable for
>   argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions:
>   propertyMissing(java.lang.String) ->> 619 | run in java.lang.Thread -
>
> ---
>
> Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/RaceTrackApp

Comment: Welcome to SO! How are we supposed to help you if you do not describe what you want to do, do not list any code that produces the error, or else show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Comment: public void run() {
 if (target != null) {
     target.run();
 }
    }

Comment: that is the line it says has something missing